# TextInputEditText freezes on Input with data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-textinputedittext

I'm using `TextInputEditText` with `databinding` - it was running fine until recently. Here's one of the layouts that got this problem:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/new_pass_confirm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/new_pass_confirm_hint"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/new_pass_confirm_et"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="@{viewmodel.enabled &amp;&amp; !viewmodel.progress}"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@={viewmodel.newPassConfirm}"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But now whenever user tries to enter anything, app freezes and `logcat` gets flooded with repeated messages over and over:

```
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ccaf106 nm : package.my ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@87ca3c7
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@e26ddb nm : package.my ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@43b078
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4fff78e nm : package.my ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@43ddbaf
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
```

The problem dissapears if I remove `android:text="@={viewmodel.newPassConfirm}"` Looks like the problem is with `val newPassConfirm = ObservableField("")` trying to change xml-field in an endless loop

It worked fine until few days ago
What I've tried:

- removing `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
- removing `android:inputType="textPassword"`
- removed each of the below from the view layer:

  ```
  binding.newPassConfirm.setOnClickListener(v -> binding.newPassConfirm.setError(null));

  binding.newPassConfirmEt.addTextChangedListener(new DefaultTextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              binding.newPassConfirm.setError(null);
          }
      });

  binding.newPassConfirmEt.setOnEditorActionListener(
                  (v, actionId, event) -> {
                      if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                              || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                              && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                          mViewModel.onOkClick();
                          return true;
                      }
                      return false;
                  });
  ```

Comment: I am experiencing this same behaviour in Jetpack Compose TextField for Android version 9. How can this be resolved in Compose? #jetpack-compose

Answer (score 0):

The reason of error was this method in DataBindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setText(TextView textView, String text) {
    textView.setText(text != null ? text : "");
}
```

It might loop itself with databinding code, resulting with massive lags

Answer (score 0):

Adding inputType="textPhonetic" in XML solved my problem:

```
android:inputType="textPhonetic"
```

Not sure which input type causes this lag. Wasted my day on this!

Comment: Do you know a fix for this in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0):

I just had same case with Ildar Ishalin.

I solved like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
@JvmStatic
fun setText(target: TextView, text: String?) {
    if (!target.text.contentEquals(text)) {
        target.text = text
    }
}
```